# Python : convert text file to dict

Tags: python

I would like to convert but I have gotten an error

```
A 123 132 21
B 34 293 91
```

---

```
d = {}
with open("ab.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        (key, val) = line.split()
        d[(key)] = val
print(d)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post, correct the formatting (there is a preview available!) and **add the full traceback**. "It has an error" may be factually correct but it does not help us help you,

Comment: What is the error

Comment: Please provide the error, and what you're trying to achieve. In other words please provide an example of a desired output.

Comment: You syntax is incorrect for decoding and assigning the values. Try using *val instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably got a "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)" error.

I am assuming you are trying to create a dictionary where the results will be:

```
d = {'A': [123, 132, 21], 'B': [34, 293, 91]}
```

If that is the case, you need:

```
d = {}
with open("ab.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        (key, *val) = line.split() # this will allow val to become a list of the remaining values
        d[key] = list(map(lambda x: int(x), val))
print(d)
```

You were just missing the `*` before `val` to cause *iterable unpacking*: **Its operand must be an iterable. The iterable is expanded into a sequence of items, which are included in the new tuple, list, or set, at the site of the unpacking.**

**Update**

From the Python manual concerning the **map**(*function*, *iterable*, ...) function:

> Return an iterator that applies *function* to every item of *iterable*, yielding the results. If additional *iterable* arguments are passed, *function* must take that many arguments and is applied to the items from all iterables in parallel. With multiple iterables, the iterator stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted. For cases where the function inputs are already arranged into argument tuples, see itertools.starmap().

In this case we use a *lambda* function as the first argument to `map`. It takes one argument and converts it to an `int`.

Then we apply the `list()` constructor to the iterator returned by the `map` function to create a list of `int` items.

Crank up an IDE (you can just type **python** with no arguments):

```
>>> val = ['123', '132', '21']
>>> m = map(lambda x: int(x), val)
>>> m
<map object at 0x00000279A94F1358>
>>> list(m)
[123, 132, 21]
```

Or:

```
>>> val = ['123', '132', '21']
>>> m = map(lambda x: int(x), val)
>>> for x in m: print(x)
...
123
132
21
```

And:

```
>>> l = lambda x, y: x + y
>>> l(7,9)
16
>>>
```

**You can also accomplish the conversion with a *list comprehension*:**

Most people find the *list comprehension* method easier to read/understand compared with using `map`, but I wanted to show you both ways:

```
d = {}
with open("ab.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        (key, *val) = line.split() # this will allow val to become a list of the remaining values
        d[key] = [int(x) for x in val]
print(d)
```

Comment: Thank you! But how do I convert dict items to int? for eg. {'A': [123, 132, 21], 'B': [34, 293, 91]}

Comment: I've just added a second method, *list comprehension* for doing the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to achieve, either:

1. replace `line.split()` with `line.split(maxsplit=1)` - this way
   values of your dict will be strings like `"123 132 21"`
2. replace `(key, val) = line.split()` with `(key, *val) = line.split()` - this way values of your dict will be lists like `[123, 132, 21]`

Comment: I've changed to this (key, *val) = line.split(). But still returns ['123', '132', '21'].

Comment: Then change `d[(key)] = val`  to  `d[key] = [int(v) for v in val]`

Answer (score 0):

The built-in function [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) splits a string wherever it finds whitespace when no separator is specified. So, using your first line as an example, the following happens:

```py
>>> 'A 123 132 21'.split()
['A', '123', '132', '21']
```

Thus, you get too many values to unpack in your definition of the tuple. To fix it, you could use the star `*` operator (I don't know the proper name for that operator) in front of your variable definition

```py
d = {}
with open("ab.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        (key, *val) = line.split()
        d[(key)] = val
print(d)

# Prints {'A': ['123', '132', '21'], 'B': ['34', '293', '91']}
```

This is explained in the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Another option is to use the named `maxsplit` parameter of the `split()` function:

```py
d = {}
with open("ab.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        (key, val) = line.split(maxsplit=1)
        d[(key)] = val.strip()
print(d)
```

Note that I had to append `strip()` when setting the entry to the dictionary to get rid of a trailing newline `\n`.

Answer (score -1):

Yon can do it this way :

```
fichier = open("ab.txt", 'r')

d = {}
for line in fichier.readlines():
    d[line[0]] = line[2:].rstrip().rsplit(' ')

print(d)
```

Output :

```
{'A': ['123', '132', '21'], 'B': ['34', '293', '91']}
```

Ask me if you don't understand something :).

Comment: Why do you assume keys will be always one-letter?

Comment: @Błotosmętek if you prefer I can .rsplit the whole line, taking the fist block of str to be the key but it's not useful in his code